# Inverse row index in a range as a variable in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table of entries for each day.
Cell B(n) should contain a sum of intermediate calculations for preceding days (n1 - nn) where one of the arguments is a delta in number of days between n and nx.

For example, given table

```
Day  A  B
1    3  0
2    5  3
3    7  11
4    8  26
5    9  49
```

values for days n=4 and n=5 are calculated as follows:

```
B4 = A1*3 + A2*2 + A3*1 + A4*0
B5 = A1*4 + A2*3 + A3*2 + A4*1 + A5*0
```

Where multipliers on the right side are deltas in days between n and nx. I imagine this to be an inverse position in a range.

```
ipos(A2,A1:A5)=3
```

Perhaps something like

```
B(n) = SUM(A1:An * ipos())
```

Any ideas how to write a formula for this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers. Maybe I did not describe the problem sufficiently.
Actually, I am trying to calculate approximate peak concentration of administered medicine for each day, given dosage for each day and half-life of the drug.

```
Day Dosage Peak
1   2,50   2,50
2   3,17   5,67
3   4,00   9,67
4   4,00   13,67
5   5,00   17,906
```

half-life (hours):

```
hl = 80
```

number of half-lives elapsed:

```
he(days_ago) = days_ago * 24 / 80
```

quantity remaining after he half lives elapsed:

```
q_n(dosage, he(days_ago)) = MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; he(days_ago))^2) * dosage
```

**And finally, total peak concentration for day n:**

```
q(n) = q_1(dosage_1, he(n-1)) + q_2(dosage_2, he(n-2)) + .. q_n(dosage_n, he(0))
```

Example, day n = 5:

```
q(5) = q_1(2,50, he(4)) + q_2(3,17, he(3)) + q_3(4,00, he(2)) + q_4(4,00, he(1)) + q_5(5,00, he(0))

q(5) = q_1(2,50, 1.2) + q_2(3,17, 0.9) + q_3(4,00, 0.6) + q_4(4,00, 0.3) + q_5(5,00, 0)

q(5) = MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; 1.2)^2) * 2,50 + MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; 0.9)^2) * 3,17 

    + MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; 0.6)^2) * 4,00 + MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; 0.3)^2) * 4,00 

    + MIN(1; 1 / MAX(1; 0)^2) * 5,00

q(5) = 0.6944 * 2,50 + 1 * 3,17 + 1 * 4,00 + 1 * 4,00 + 1 * 5,00
q(5) = 17.906
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the power of mixed references.

=IF(ISNUMBER(C1),C1+SUM($B$1:B1),0)

Copy down.

[image]

Comment: ..........Beautiful approach ! .................

Answer (score 1):

This is a Visual Basic user defined function *(UDF)*;

```
Public Function iSum(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim K As Long
    K = rng.Count - 1

    For Each r In rng
        iSum = iSum + K * r
        K = K - 1
    Next r
End Function
```

[image]

It is probably possible to do this with *SUMPRODUCT()*, but I can't figure out how to do the multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight your cells including the column titles
2. Insert Table (check that you have a header row)
3. Change your table name to "MyTable" or something. (While your selection is within the table, the table name should be on the left end of the Table Tools Design ribbon.)
4. For each cell in B, change the formula to `=IF(ROW()-ROW(MyTable[#Headers])=1,0,OFFSET([@B],-1,0)+SUM(OFFSET(MyTable[[#Headers],[A]],1,0,ROW()-ROW(MyTable[#Headers])-1)))`

Edit: I should explain this formula. Translated to English it says...

- If I'm the first data row in the table then just return 0
- Otherwise, return the cell above me plus the sum of the values in A above me.